# How can I avoid vertical margin between block elements?

Tags: html, css, margin

Given a page with three block elements below each other (here: `header`, `main` and `footer`), I'd like to ensure that there is no vertical margin between the three elements. The problem is that the content of the `main` element is generated (using a templating language) and I cannot make too many assumptions about the contained markup.

Consider this example: note how I already explicitly omitted the bottom margin of the caption and the top margin of the first paragraph. Alas, using `main > *:last-child` won't work for the `p` nested in a `li` element. Is there a way to generalise this such that a margin of e.g. a `p` nested in a `li` is omitted, too?

```css
header {
  background-color: red;
}

main {
  background-color: green;
}

footer {
  background-color: blue;
}

h1 {
  margin-bottom: 0
}

main > *:first-child {
  margin-top: 0
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>
    Hello
  </h1>
</header>
<main>
  <p>
    Some content
  </p>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <p>
        Some list item
      </p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</main>
<footer>
  There should be no white gap above!
</footer>
```

I'd like the `main` element to have no margin at the bottom whatsoever (not even by a nested element such as the `p` elements here), such that the `footer` element comes right below it.

Comment: `overflow: auto;` on main ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif Much better solution!

Comment: read the duplicate to understand the *why*

Comment: Pity, I now see that I simplified my question too much: using `overflow: auto` doesn't work in my case since it _also_ resets the `overflow-x: visible` I'm using (I use some `:before`/`:after` pseudo elements to add shadows to the left and right, which get clipped with `overflow: auto`).

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this for your specific case. May be with other content in `main` other problems could be appear.

```css
header {
  background-color: red;
}

main {
  background-color: green;
}

footer {
  background-color: blue;
}

h1 {
  margin-bottom: 0
}

main > *:first-child {
  margin-top: 0
}
main *:last-child {
   margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>
    Hello
  </h1>
</header>
<main>
  <p>
    Some content
  </p>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <p>
        Some list item
      </p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</main>
<footer>
  There should be no white gap above!
</footer>
```

Comment: Sure, I could do this - I was rather hoping for something which makes no assumptions of the contents in `main`.